# who can help me creating methods? mystring.replacefirst(string,string); and replace(since,until,string); for j2me please

Tags: java, java-me

i need those two method than j2me doesnt have i have found one replaceall(); but it is

```
replaceall(string,string,string);
```

secund method is of `SringBuffer`
but in j2me it doesn't have  replace(since,until,string) 
i had done a code in java, than need these method but now i want to pass it to j2me i have the surprise it doesnt have :(

Comment: you need to be more specific about which methods you need to implement.  It is not sufficient to just give the type signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution: http://www.itgalary.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=871

You have to create it yourself since it doesn't exist in J2ME